# MailMessage with HTML embedded image not displaying in windows 8 email clients

Tags: c#, html, email

I have a C# app that generates emails using an HTML format (AlternateView) that contains an embedded image (jpeg).

The emails can be viewed correctly on Android, iOS, Outlook (2010) on Windows, but not on the native email client on Windows 8/8.1 Phone and Tablet (although it works find in Outlook running on the Win 8.1 tablet).

However the offending email client on the Win 8 phones/tablets can correctly see emails with embedded images sent from Outlook running on a PC.

The only thing I could find was to make sure the ContentType is set on the LinkedResource -which I do in the constructor:
LinkedResource pic1 = new LinkedResource(imgPath, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

Code below.

Any suggestions?

```
string picId = "Pic1-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string htmlBody = "<html><body><h1>Test Message</h1><img src=\"cid:" + picId + "\"></body></html>";
AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
  (htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

// Create a LinkedResource object for each embedded image
LinkedResource pic1 = new LinkedResource(imgPath, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

pic1.ContentId = picId;
avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(pic1);


// Add the alternate views instead of using MailMessage.Body
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
m.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

// Address and send the message
m.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress, fromName);
m.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress)); 
m.Subject = subject;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(AsbSmtpServer);

client.Send(m);
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders - "C#" is a programming language - not a hash tag.

Comment: @TheHuff not sure will it solve your issue..just add `m.IsBodyHtml = true;` before sending the mail..

Comment: Having the same issue using WP8.1 and cannot find any solution as well.